# Kill a process that is owned by a different user in VB6

Tags: winapi, vb6

I need to be able to kill a process that is running under a different user. Here is the scenerio User 1 (admin or standard user) switches users but leaves application A running. User 2 (standard user) logs on to that same machine when they log into application A i need to kill the process that is running Application A under user 1. I have the default admin user name and password in the db. What I have done will kill the process if they are both admin but not if user 2 is a standard user. How do i kill a processes as a different user? here is what I have so far.

```
Const MAX_PATH& = 260


Private Declare Function TerminateProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal ApphProcess As Long, ByVal uExitCode As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal blnheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwAppProcessId As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ProcessFirst Lib "kernel32" Alias "Process32First" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, uProcess As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
Private Declare Function ProcessNext Lib "kernel32" Alias "Process32Next" (ByVal hSnapshot As Long, uProcess As PROCESSENTRY32) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateToolhelpSnapshot Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot" (ByVal lFlags As Long, lProcessID As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long

Private Type LUID
    lowpart As Long
    highpart As Long
End Type

Private Type TOKEN_PRIVILEGES
    PrivilegeCount As Long
    LuidUDT As LUID
    Attributes As Long
End Type

Const TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = &H20
Const TOKEN_QUERY = &H8
Const SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = &H2
Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = &H1F0FFF

Private Declare Function GetVersion Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetCurrentProcess Lib "kernel32" () As Long
Private Declare Function OpenProcessToken Lib "advapi32" (ByVal ProcessHandle As Long, ByVal DesiredAccess As Long, TokenHandle As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function LookupPrivilegeValue Lib "advapi32" Alias "LookupPrivilegeValueA" (ByVal lpSystemName As String, ByVal lpName As String, lpLuid As LUID) As Long
Private Declare Function AdjustTokenPrivileges Lib "advapi32" (ByVal TokenHandle As Long, ByVal DisableAllPrivileges As Long, NewState As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES, ByVal BufferLength As Long, PreviousState As Any, ReturnLength As Any) As Long

Private Type PROCESSENTRY32
    dwSize As Long
    cntUsage As Long
    th32ProcessID As Long
    th32DefaultHeapID As Long
    th32ModuleID As Long
    cntThreads As Long
    th32ParentProcessID As Long
    pcPriClassBase As Long
    dwFlags As Long
    szexeFile As String * MAX_PATH
End Type

     Public Function KillApp(myName As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo HandleError

    Const TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS As Long = 2&
    Const PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0
    Dim uProcess As PROCESSENTRY32
    Dim rProcessFound As Long
    Dim hSnapshot As Long
    Dim szExename As String
    Dim ExitCode As Long
    Dim myProcess As Long
    Dim AppKill As Boolean
    Dim appCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim processKilled As Boolean
    Dim WMI, QRY, ListOfProcesses, Item, ProcessUserName, colProperties

    appCount = 0

    uProcess.dwSize = Len(uProcess)
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelpSnapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0&)
    rProcessFound = ProcessFirst(hSnapshot, uProcess)

    Do While rProcessFound
        i = InStr(1, uProcess.szexeFile, Chr(0))
        szExename = LCase$(Left$(uProcess.szexeFile, i - 1))
        If Right$(szExename, Len(myName)) = LCase$(myName) Then
            'set the queryfor the process object for this process
            QRY = "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" + myName + "'"

            'Set up the Windows Management Instrumentation object
            Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}\\.\root\cimv2")

            Set ListOfProcesses = WMI.ExecQuery(QRY)

            For Each Item In ListOfProcesses
            'Get the user name
            colProperties = Item.GetOwner(ProcessUserName)
            'Only kill the processes if its not your user name
                If Not ProcessUserName = Environ("USERNAME") Then
                    KillApp = True
                    appCount = appCount + 1
                    myProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, False, uProcess.th32ProcessID)
                    processKilled = KillProcess(uProcess.th32ProcessID, 0)
                End If
            Next
        End If
    rProcessFound = ProcessNext(hSnapshot, uProcess)
    Loop

    Call CloseHandle(hSnapshot)

    Exit Function
    HandleError:
        bErrorHandler.Error_Handler_Debug Err.Number, "We have encountered an error while starting CAD. This is usually because there is another user logged on to this machine with CAD or Dispatch running and we could not close out there session. Please log off all other users and try to start CAD again. The following is an error message generated by the system: " + Err.Description, "frmCADMainMDI.KillApp"
    End Function

    Function KillProcess(ByVal hProcessID As Long, Optional ByVal ExitCode As Long) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    Dim htoken As Long
    Dim hProcess As Long
    Dim tp As TOKEN_PRIVILEGES


    If GetVersion() >= 0 Then

        If OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES Or TOKEN_QUERY, htoken) = 0 Then
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        If LookupPrivilegeValue("", "SeDebugPrivilege", tp.LuidUDT) = 0 Then
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If

        tp.PrivilegeCount = 1
        tp.Attributes = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED

        If AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, False, tp, 0, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&) = 0 Then
            GoTo CleanUp
        End If
    End If

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, hProcessID)
    If hProcess Then
        KillProcess = (TerminateProcess(hProcess, ExitCode) <> 0)
        ' close the process handle
        CloseHandle hProcess
    End If

    If GetVersion() >= 0 Then
        ' under NT restore original privileges
        tp.Attributes = 0
        AdjustTokenPrivileges htoken, False, tp, 0, ByVal 0&, ByVal 0&
    End If

    CleanUp:
    If htoken Then
        CloseHandle htoken
    End If

    Exit Function
    HandleError:
        bErrorHandler.Error_Handler_Debug Err.Number, Err.Description, "frmCADMainMDI.KillProcess"
    End Function
```

KillApp is called during the load event of the application with the nameofprogram.exe as the param. I am trying to stay away from shell calls because there are some instances cmd line and shell are disabled in the end user environment

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think there's any straightforward way to do that.  In the default configuration, you could use CreateProcessWithLogonW if the built-in Administrator account is enabled and you have the password, but that won't work for any other admin account.  It isn't a sensible thing to do anyway, because the non-admin user B could steal the default admin password.  Instead, you could have application A listen on a TCP port and kill itself if it receives a connection, or you could install a system service to do the work that requires admin privilege.

Comment: So instead of starting the application A as the user, start it as the default admin, and then I could kill that application as the default admin. How do i specify which user to use to kill the application as? @HarryJohnston

Comment: Assuming that both users are allowed to know the default admin password, and that it doesn't matter if A runs in a different context than the user who is using it (e.g., it doesn't have to write files to the user's document folder) - yes, that approach might work.  Ingenious!  You can launch A as the default admin using CreateProcessWithLogonW.  Note that A won't be run with admin privilege, i.e., it will get a restricted token rather than an elevated one.  To kill the old process as the default admin, just run KillProcess from A, or from any other process that is running as the default admin.

Comment: One potential catch is that I'm not certain offhand what permissions are set on a process launched by CreateProcessWithLogonW, i.e., whether they are based on the user that launched the process or the user the process is running as.  But if that does turn out to be a problem it should be easy to work around, just launch a proxy process as the default admin and have that process launch A with plain old CreateProcess.  Or you could manipulate the process permissions directly, using the process handle CreateProcessWithLogonW gives you.

Comment: ... come to think of it, you could instead run A as the current user (with CreateProcess) but manipulate its permissions to give the default admin account access to kill it.  That would avoid any problems due to A running in a different context.

Comment: @HarryJohnston ok so I have run into some problems with this. So i decided to think about it a different way. Is there some way to tap into the windows switch user event?

Comment: Depends what you mean.  You can monitor logon and logoff events from a service, for example.  I don't know whether an application can detect that the user has selected "switch user" but that isn't the only way for another user to log on ... they could Remote Desktop in for example.  On server editions (or hacked systems) there can be more than one user active simultaneously.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Good point I may end up just creating a windows service that kills the process when a new process with the same name is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I kill a process as a different user?

To answer just that part of the question, since it seems to be the aspect you're most interested in, I believe that (unless your program is running with elevated privilege) the only robust way to kill a target process X using the context of a specific account Y (for which you have the credentials) is to launch a child process running in the context of Y to kill X on your behalf.

You can do that using the [CreateProcessWithLogonW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682431(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

One caveat: if Y is an administrator, and UAC is enabled, the child process will run with a limited token, not an elevated token.  So you can't use this approach to take advantage of administrative credentials.  However, if the permissions on X give access to Y directly, rather than only to the Administrators group, it should still work.

(In your specific scenario, that may mean that you need to explicitly set or change the permissions on the process as part of launching the application A.  If you use CreateProcess, you can assign explicit permissions to the new process using the `lpProcessAttributes` parameter.)

---

Note in particular that you cannot use impersonation unless you have SeImpersonatePrivilege, which by default is only granted to administrators and system services, so that approach is unlikely to succeed.  (The documentation says that you can impersonate a token without SeImpersonatePrivilege if you created the token yourself using explicit credentials, but in practice this does not appear to be true.)

Comment: ok I will check this out and get back to you thanks for your help.

Comment: This does work. But not for my situation but it does answer the question perfectly.